# Organizational chart using google visualization api that reads names from an CSV file?

Tags: php, jquery, json, csv, google-visualization

I'm trying to make an organizational chart using google charts api .. like this

http://jsfiddle.net/hisham91/pbkuok2u/

but i want it to read the names from a **CSV file** that has a big data over a 500 employee >> how can i do this please help ?

```
Thanks,
Best Regards, 
Hisham
```

**UPDATE BELOW :**

Code for method 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

 function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'address.csv');

    // Apply query language statement.
    query.setQuery('SELECT * ');

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    visualization = new google.visualization.orgchart(document.getElementById('address_chart'));
    visualization.draw(data, {legend: 'bottom'});
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="address_chart" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for method 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["orgchart"]});

        $(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                data:'orgChart2.php',
                url:'address.csv',
                success:function(data){
                    var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'Employee');
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

                    dt.addRows(data);


                    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('address_chart'));
                    chart.draw(dt, {allowHtml:true});

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="address_chart" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

note: nothing displaying - blank page.

Noting too that my address.csv file contains as below :

```
**Employee     Manager**
Darren Parker  
Tanja Plate    Darren Parker
Allie Bellew   Darren Parker
Franz Kohl     Tanja Plate
Cindy White    Allie Bellew
Chris Norred   Cindy White
```

Comment: If you want to build an organizational chart , the data should be organized and passed to the data.addRow

Comment: yea sam i know , they are organized did u check my csv file i want the data to be passed through csv file i can't add an addrow for every employee !! :/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the task done is writing a query in the java-script itself ,to fetch the data from the CSV Chart,
you can get the data into the array

you can try this code for retrieving data from csv

```
   function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'your sheet source here');

    // Apply query language statement.
    query.setQuery('SELECT A,D WHERE D > 100 ORDER BY D');

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    visualization.draw(data, {legend: 'bottom'});
  }
```

you can find more Information [Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews)

Another method to do this is write a ajax function to get the data of your employees

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["orgchart"]});
        $(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                data:'urlOfyourpage',
                url:'urlofthepage',
                success:function(data){
                    var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'Namess');
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

                    dt.addRows(data);


                    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(dt, {allowHtml:true});

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

you will be needing to organize child and parent according to the data you acquire.